# How does one subtract hours from an NSDate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I would like to subtract 4 hours from a date. I read the date string into an NSDate object use the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate * mydate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dict objectForKey:@"published"]];
```

What do I do next?

Comment: (It's now 6 years, and 4 major versions of XCode later... and NSDate's functionality is still as unintuitive as in 2009 !!)

Answer (score 49):

```
NSDate *newDate = [theDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-3600*4];
```

[Link to documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/dateByAddingTimeInterval:).

---

```
NSDate *newDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:-3600*4
                                              sinceDate:theDate]] autorelease];
```

[Link to documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:).

Answer (score 23):

NSCalendar is the general API for changing dates based on human time units. For this, you can use NSCalendar's [`-dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:) with a negative number of hours.

Comment: NSCalendar is not a recommended API to use. http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendarDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @norskben: That page is for NSCalendar**Date**. That's what it says not to use. It specifically recommends NSCalendar as a replacement in the same note.

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 4 :

```
var baseDate = ... // something
let dateMinus4Hours = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -4, to: baseDate)
```

don't go with `24*3600` and stuff, that's asking for trouble.

Answer (score 6):

Since iOS 8 there is the more convenient `dateByAddingUnit`:

**Swift 2.x**

```
//subtract 3 hours
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Hour, value: -3, toDate: originalDate, options: [])
```

Comment: Comment says subtract however 3 was used as value it should instead be -3

Answer (score 5):

```
//in Swift 3
//subtract 3 hours
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrent
newDate = calendar.date(byAdding:.hour, value: -3, to: originalDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a function which might be useful as it returns the date -4 h considering that this may also change the date and the month and eventually the year. the .searchBackward option is the important part :)

```
public static func correctSecondComponent(date: Date, calendar: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian))->Date {

    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)

    let e = (calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: NSCalendar.Unit.hour, value: -4, to: date, options:.searchBackwards)!

    return e
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dateFromString function returns NSDate, not NSString. 
you should change,

> NSDate * theDate = [dateFormatter
>   dateFromString:datetemp];