# How to subtract 1 hour from a given date/time

Tags: objective-c, ios, datetime

I want to get the date / time an hour before a given date / time.

Let's say the given date / time is 2012-11-25 13:20:35 (YYYY-mm-dd hour:minute:second).

Comment: If you can get the epoch time (I'm not familiar with this language), you can subtract 3600 from it to get the hour prior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934873/calculating-time-difference-in-objective-c

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160977/how-does-one-subtract-hours-from-an-nsdate

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158299/how-to-get-the-date-a-week-in-the-past-from-today/6158401#6158401

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use:

```
NSDate *minusOneHr = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*60];
```

Comment: Gives one hour before the current time, not before a given time, unlike my answer which the asker has just unaccepted.

Answer (score 15):

You should read [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) in the Apple documentation.

Here's something to get you on your way:

```
NSTimeInterval secondsPerHour = 60 * 60;
NSDate *givenDate = ...; // what you have already
NSDate *earlierDate = [givenDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondsPerHour];
```

Note the minus sign in front of secondsPerHour, since it's earlier.

Comment: I think OP was just marking as accepted which one was earlier, they are similar enough that it's easy for any coder to see which params to replace w/ their own date variable. I upvoted both for good measure though