# Add /subtract minutes to or from NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I need to subtract 15 minutes from a date.  Note understanding why following is not working:

```
eventDate = event.date;
            NSDate *alarmDate = [[eventDate] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*15];//this is throwing error "Expected identifier"
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Get rid of the needless brackets around `eventDate`.

Comment: Did not fix problem.  Code is from this answer that received 9 votes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420199/how-to-subtract-1-hour-from-a-given-date-time.  Funny how random SO ratings are.

Comment: Huge difference. Those brackets are for calling a method. Your brackets around `evenDate` are invalid and causing your error.

Comment: why would you comment on question and then try to close it?  Thank you Abhi for actually answering the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a syntax error in your code, square braces must only be used when you are sending a "message" to an object. Do not use Objective-C square brace syntax in any other situation.

Here is the correct code:

```
eventDate = event.date;
NSDate *alarmDate = [eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*15];
```